# Como insertar un objeto dentro de un arreglo a partir de otro arreglo

Tags: javascript

el código es el siguiente:

```
let a = [{marca: "ford", modelo:"chevete"}]
let b = [];
b.push({a[0].marca: ´${a[0].modelo}´}); //aquí es donde tengo el error
```

quisiera introducir a los datos del arreglo 'a' como clave y valor del arreglo 'b' pero no se como se debe hacer exactamente

Comment: `b.push(a[0]);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
let a = [{marca: "ford", modelo:"chevete"}]
let b = [];

console.log(a); // [ { marca: 'ford', modelo: 'chevete' } ]

let objeto = {};
objeto[a[0].marca] = a[0].modelo;

b.push(objeto);

console.log(b); // [ { ford: 'chevete' } ]
```